# Is OCI_ATTR_FNCODE deprecated?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-call-interface

OCI_ATTR_FNCODE returns OCI function codes.
I can't find any OCI_ATTR_FNCODE references after oracle 8 documentation.
Was it deprecated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh. Yes. That's no more available. OCIUserCallBackRegister() can be used to register entry/exit callback functions for the OCI API using their function codes though. In case you want to trace.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnoci/user-defined-callback-functions.html#GUID-7CC81F1D-0EB3-464A-B87F-CF4F18BCBA7C

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is non functional now. What functionality are you looking for?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow! This answer should provide evidence to confirm it's validity as well as not have open ended questions. This seems like it'd be a better fit as a comment on the original question :)

Comment: I want to get function code of the last OCI operation on a handle, such as OCIInitialize , OCIHandleAlloc, OCIHandleFree and so on. OCI_ATTR_SQLFNCODE returns the function code of the SQL command associated with the statement. It's not what I want.